# Memory addressing with GNU Assember Intel Syntax

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

I read [this page](http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpas86.html) containing a good list of differences between Intel and AT&T syntax for GAS but it did not cover the case of specifying an address with a displacement only.

Here I've assembled four lines with AT&T syntax:

```
                         .text
0000 48C7C008000000      mov    $8, %rax
0007 488B042508000000    mov    (8), %rax
000f 4889F0              mov    %rsi, %rax
0012 488B06              mov    (%rsi), %rax
```

The first two lines are different, as expected.  The first moves the immediate value 8 into rax and the second moves the contents of address 8 into rax.  But with Intel syntax I get the following odd behavior:

```
                         .text
                         .intel_syntax
0000 48C7C008000000      mov    %rax, 8
0007 48C7C008000000      mov    %rax, [8]
000e 4889F0              mov    %rax, %rsi
0011 488B06              mov    %rax, [%rsi]
```

Here the first and second lines assembled to the *same* machine code!  First I thought the square brackets were wrong, so I added the third and fourth lines to the test, and the square brackets do work for memory addressing at least when registers are involved.

All of the documentation I have read show memory addressing examples with at least a base or index register, and sometimes a scale and displacement, but never a displacement only.

I do have experience with the Intel syntax using the NASM assembler, which *does* distinguish `mov rax, 8` and `mov rax, [8]`.

Is this a bug in GAS?  Or if not, how do I specify the equivalent of NASM's `mov rax, [8]`?

I realize it is probably uncommon to specify a displacement-only address but I would like to get a complete understanding of all of the memory addressing forms with this syntax.

Comment: When I assemble your example with Intel syntax, I *do* get the expected behavior. For me, the generated machine code is exactly the same as what you show except the second line, which is `48 8b 04 25 08 00 00` for me.

Comment: If in the above _Intel Syntax_ example to GAS you got the shown output then yes, your version GAS created incorrect code for `mov %rax, 8` (which initializes `rax` with the _constant_ 8, same as AT&T `mov $8, %rax`). All the addressing operations, as present, use the correct opcodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was indeed such a bug in `gas` -- see http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10637 .

It appears to be fixed in (or perhaps before) binutils 2.21.51.

Comment: Wow, I did not find that on a search.  Indeed `gcc -v` gives "GNU assembler version 2.20.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.20.1-system.20100303" so I will update to 2.21.x and give it a shot.

Comment: Verified on the new binutils.  Thanks @Matthew.

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing a very special corner case of AT&T syntax here. Ordinarily, for address operands, you have:

```
<op> [ src, ] displacement(base,index,scale) [, tgt ]
```

Any of the constituents of an address operand in AT&T syntax are optional, so you can write `mov (%rax, %rbx), ...` or `mov 0(%rax, %rbx, 1), ...` or any other such combination.

*Inside* the `()` brackets the only number you ordinarily can have is the scale factor (if present).

But the assembler also accepts (and creates identical code for):

```
mov <absolute>, ...
mov (<absolute>), ...
```

This works only if the operand inside the `()` is a simple number / absolute address, otherwise the assembler complains that what you gave isn't a valid scale factor. This equivalence is a *special case* in AT&T syntax - I'm not sure why it was/is allowed.

The use of `$` in AT&T syntax, though, always specifies a *constant*, not an address operand, which is the same as a *naked number* in Intel Syntax.

The following illustrates the equivalences:

```
$ cat t.s
        mov     (8), %rax
        mov     $8, %rax
        mov     8, %rax
.intel_syntax
        mov %rax, [ 8 ]
        mov %rax, 8
        mov %rax, %ds:8

$ objdump -w -d t.o

t.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   48 8b 04 25 08 00 00 00         mov    0x8,%rax
   8:   48 c7 c0 08 00 00 00            mov    $0x8,%rax
   f:   48 8b 04 25 08 00 00 00         mov    0x8,%rax
  17:   48 8b 04 25 08 00 00 00         mov    0x8,%rax
  1f:   48 c7 c0 08 00 00 00            mov    $0x8,%rax
  26:   48 8b 04 25 08 00 00 00         mov    0x8,%rax

$ objdump -w -M intel -d t.o

t.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 :
   0:   48 8b 04 25 08 00 00 00         mov    rax,ds:0x8
   8:   48 c7 c0 08 00 00 00            mov    rax,0x8
   f:   48 8b 04 25 08 00 00 00         mov    rax,ds:0x8
  17:   48 8b 04 25 08 00 00 00         mov    0x8,%rax
  1f:   48 c7 c0 08 00 00 00            mov    rax,0x8
  26:   48 8b 04 25 08 00 00 00         mov    rax,ds:0x8
```

Comment: The question is about the odd behaviour of the Intel syntax; but...  I don't think the AT&T syntax here is a special case -- I suspect that it's just evaluating `(8)` as an expression, because it doesn't match anything that *is* special syntax.  e.g. `mov 8, %rax`, `mov (8), %rax`, `mov 4+4, %rax` and `mov (4+4), %rax` all do the same thing.